# Error when trying to fill in registration fields

Tags: php, variables, authentication, isset

I'm trying to create a login and registration system with PHP for a school assignment, but it's currently not really working...

The problem is it generates an error saying the fields are empty, even when you filled the fields in with data, so it shouldn't give this error.

The code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Music Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" type="text/css" />
    <?php
        // Verbinden met de database //
        include('connect.php');

        // Registreer data verkrijgen en in variabelen zetten //
        if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
            $r_username = $_POST['r_username']; 
            $r_password = $_POST['r_password'];
            $confirm_r_password = $_POST['confirm_r_password']; 
            $r_name = $_POST['r_name']; 
            $r_surname = $_POST['r_surname'];
            $r_birth = $_POST['r_dateofbirth'];
            $r_mail = $_POST['r_mail'];
        }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <form name="login" action="login.php" method="post">
            <p>Login: <input class="input" type="text" name="username" value="Username" />
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="Password" /></p>
            <div><a class="link" href="register.php">Register here!</a></div>
            <p align="center"><input class="submit" type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <a class="link" href="index.php">Music Database</a>
    </div>
    <div id="search">
        <form name="search" action="search.php" method="post">
            <p>Search for: <input class="input" type="text" name="search" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['search'])) print $_POST['search']; ?>" />
            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="search_submit" value="Submit" /></p>
            <p>Artist: <input type="checkbox" name="artistsearch" checked /> 
            Album: <input type="checkbox" name="albumsearch" /> 
            Song: <input type="checkbox" name="songsearch" /> 
            Genre: <input type="checkbox" name="genresearch" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper"><br /></div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Register down here please:</h1>
        <table id="wrap_table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="reg_content">
                    <div id="reg_form">
                        <form name="register_login" action="register.php" method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                            <legend>Login Data: </legend>
                                <table class="r_table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Username<sup>*</sup>: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_username" value="<?php if(isset($r_username)){ print $_POST['r_username']; }  ?>"/></td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
                                                if(!isset($r_username)){
                                                    echo "<td>Error: No Username has been entered!</td>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Password<sup>*</sup>: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="password" name="r_password" value="<?php if(isset($r_password)){ print $_POST['r_password']; }  ?>"/></td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
                                                if(!isset($r_password)){
                                                    echo "<td>Error: No Password has been entered!</td>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Confirm Password<sup>*</sup>: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="password" name="confirm_r_password"  value="<?php if(isset($confirm_r_password)){ print $_POST['confirm_r_password']; }  ?>"/></td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($confirm_password)){
                                                if($confirm_r_password != $r_password){
                                                    echo "<td>Error: The passwords don't match!</td>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="reg_form">
                        <form name="register_personal" action="register.php" method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                            <legend>Personal Data: </legend>
                                <table class="r_table_personal">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Name: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_name" value=""/></td>                              
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Surname: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_surname" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Date of Birth: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_dateofbirth"  value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>E-mail<sup>*</sup>: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_mail" value="<?php if(isset($r_mail)){ print $_POST['r_mail']; } ?>"/></td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
                                                if(!isset($r_mail)){
                                                    echo "<td>Error: No E-mail has been entered!</td>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fields with an asterisk<sup>*</sup> are required for registry!
                    <div id="reg_content">
                        <form name="submit_registry" action="register.php" method="post">
                            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="r_submit" value="Submit!" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footerbreak"><br /></div>
    <div id="footer"> &copy; Jorik ter Molen &amp; Camiel Collet, 2011.</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are the 2 pieces of code in different php files? What is the execution order? If you execute the html part **before** the second piece of code, you'll get that error because the `$r_username`, `$r_password`, etc variables are not defines

Comment: The PHP part is first executed and afterwards the HTML, also the html part is inside a form, but took the form away because of the code being gigantic then :P Could still add it if people want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

do you have your `<form action="" method="post">` in there?

you can also debug your $_POST global to see whats happening (if data is hitting your script)

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: The var_dump generates this line: "array(1) { ["r_submit"]=> string(7) "Submit!" } " even when data has been put in the text fields, so I guess the _POST never received the username etc.

Answer (score 0):

So you include the first "form" page in the second php file after the code right?

First of all in the PHP file you should add all the

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

segments into one:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $r_username = $_POST['r_username'];
    $r_password = $_POST['r_password'];
    $confirm_r_password = $_POST['confirm_r_password']; 
    $r_name = $_POST['r_name']; 
    $r_surname = $_POST['r_surname'];
    $r_birth = $_POST['r_dateofbirth'];
    $r_mail = $_POST['r_mail'];
}
```

Your problem is most probably in $_POST['submit'] since you have two checks, one for $_POST['submit'] and another for $_POST['r_submit']

Unless you send it both ways i suggest you change the PHP file to check for 'r_submit'

## Update:

Try putting the form inside the register.php page so it looks like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
        $r_username = $_POST['r_username'];
        $r_password = $_POST['r_password'];
        $confirm_r_password = $_POST['confirm_r_password']; 
    } 

?>

<form action="register.php" method="post">

    <td>Username<sup>*</sup>: </td>
        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_username" value="<?php     if(isset($r_username)){ print $_POST['r_username']; }  ?>"/></td>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
            if(!isset($r_username)){
                echo "<td>Error: No Username has been entered!</td>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password<sup>*</sup>: </td>
    <td><input class="input" type="password" name="r_password" value="<?php if(isset($r_password)){ print $_POST['r_password']; }  ?>"/></td>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
            if(!isset($r_password)){
                echo "<td>Error: No Password has been entered!</td>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Confirm Password<sup>*</sup>: </td>
    <td><input class="input" type="password" name="confirm_r_password"  value="<?php if(isset($confirm_r_password)){ print $_POST['confirm_r_password']; }  ?>"/></td>
    <?php
        if(isset($confirm_password)){
            if($confirm_r_password != $r_password){
                echo "<td>Error: The passwords don't match!</td>";
            }
        }
    ?>
   </tr>

<input name="r_submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />   
</form>
```

## Solution:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Music Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" type="text/css" />
    <?php

        // Verbinden met de database //
        include('connect.php');

        // Registreer data verkrijgen en in variabelen zetten //
        if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
            $r_username = $_POST['r_username']; 
            $r_password = $_POST['r_password'];
            $confirm_r_password = $_POST['confirm_r_password']; 
            $r_name = $_POST['r_name']; 
            $r_surname = $_POST['r_surname'];
            $r_birth = $_POST['r_dateofbirth'];
            $r_mail = $_POST['r_mail'];
        }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login">
        <form name="login" action="login.php" method="post">
            <p>Login: <input class="input" type="text" name="username" value="Username" />
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="Password" /></p>
            <div><a class="link" href="register.php">Register here!</a></div>
            <p align="center"><input class="submit" type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="header">
        <a class="link" href="index.php">Music Database</a>
    </div>
    <div id="search">
        <form name="search" action="search.php" method="post">
            <p>Search for: <input class="input" type="text" name="search" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['search'])) print $_POST['search']; ?>" />
            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="search_submit" value="Submit" /></p>
            <p>Artist: <input type="checkbox" name="artistsearch" checked /> 
            Album: <input type="checkbox" name="albumsearch" /> 
            Song: <input type="checkbox" name="songsearch" /> 
            Genre: <input type="checkbox" name="genresearch" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper"><br /></div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Register down here please:</h1>
        <table id="wrap_table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="reg_content">
                    <div id="reg_form">
                        <form name="register_login" action="register.php" method="post">
                            <fieldset>
                            <legend>Login Data: </legend>
                                <table class="r_table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Username<sup>*</sup>: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_username" value="<?php if(isset($r_username)){ print $_POST['r_username']; }  ?>"/></td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
                                                if(!isset($r_username)){
                                                    echo "<td>Error: No Username has been entered!</td>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Password<sup>*</sup>: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="password" name="r_password" value="<?php if(isset($r_password)){ print $_POST['r_password']; }  ?>"/></td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
                                                if(!isset($r_password)){
                                                    echo "<td>Error: No Password has been entered!</td>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Confirm Password<sup>*</sup>: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="password" name="confirm_r_password"  value="<?php if(isset($confirm_r_password)){ print $_POST['confirm_r_password']; }  ?>"/></td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($confirm_password)){
                                                if($confirm_r_password != $r_password){
                                                    echo "<td>Error: The passwords don't match!</td>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="reg_form">

                            <fieldset>
                            <legend>Personal Data: </legend>
                                <table class="r_table_personal">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Name: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_name" value=""/></td>                              
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Surname: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_surname" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Date of Birth: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_dateofbirth"  value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>E-mail<sup>*</sup>: </td>
                                        <td><input class="input" type="text" name="r_mail" value="<?php if(isset($r_mail)){ print $_POST['r_mail']; } ?>"/></td>
                                        <?php
                                            if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
                                                if(!isset($r_mail)){
                                                    echo "<td>Error: No E-mail has been entered!</td>";
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fields with an asterisk<sup>*</sup> are required for registry!
                  <div id="reg_content">

                            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="r_submit" value="Submit!" />
                            </div>
                      </form>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footerbreak"><br /></div>
    <div id="footer"> &copy; Jorik ter Molen &amp; Camiel Collet, 2011.</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Changed it into the correct "r_submit", but get another couple of errors generated by the PHP itself now:
"Notice: Undefined index: r_username in C:\xampp\htdocs\MusicDatabase\register.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: r_password in C:\xampp\htdocs\MusicDatabase\register.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: confirm_r_password in C:\xampp\htdocs\MusicDatabase\register.php on line 13"

etc.

Comment: Something is wrong with your form then as it does not recognize the post variables you send.

Do you use method="post" in your form declaration?

Comment: Check the "updated" answer and tell us if you still get errors

Comment: The PHP and the HTML are already in the same document, i'll post the whole code, maybe that will sort it out ;)

Comment: There you have it. Your problem is because the submit button is in a different form then the registration input textboxes.

Put all textboxes for the registration along with the submit button inside the same form.

Comment: Try the suggested solution above.

Comment: Yes! It works now :). Thanks for your help!
Also do you know some login scripts or what's the best way to create them? Thanks!

Comment: Something else turned up now, the confirm password doesn't work (anymore)... :(

Comment: I have answered in a new answer below. Also please click the correct answer if satisfied with the solution, if you'd like to help others with similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Around line 82 where you have the php check for the matching passwords, replace it with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['r_submit'])){
    if($confirm_r_password != $r_password)
    {
          echo "<td>Error: The passwords don't match!</td>";
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Although this is just a basic check and nothing secure since the user can leave both passwords empty and they still match.